# static_cast и (int) - это одно и то же?

Tags: c++, c++-faq

Не могу понять, зачем `static_cast`, если всё то же можно сделать с помощью прямого указания типа.

Comment: ещё вопрос к cast-ам. dynamic_cast, есть такая фишка.
Der2 der2 = new Der2;
Der der = dynamic_cast<Der *> (der2);
Der и Der2 - не являются потомками или являются, в общем потом я пытаюсь сделать der->метод_класса_Der2, и нельзя, зачем тогда преобразование, что оно дает, возможно я туплю, но я бы хотел все же это узнать, спасибо.

Comment: Ну, ваш объект же _на самом деле_ не `Der`, правда? А что вы ожидаете -- что `dynamic_cast` за вас из воздуха вытащит объект класса `Der` по объекту класса `Der2`? Если ваш объект на самом деле _является_ экземпляром `Der`, то `dynamic_cast` сработает.

Кстати, у вас опечатка: надо

    Der* pder = dynamic_cast<Der*>(&der2);

т.к. `dynamic_cast` работает с указателями.

Comment: спасибо вроде разобрался)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Очень избитая тема. Зачем нужен? ну потому, что у них немного разное поведение.  [Здесь](http://alenacpp.blogspot.com/2005/08/c.html) есть очень хорошая статья, которая описывает разницу.

Вот цитата с ответом на вопрос

> > Что делает приведение типов в стиле С: пытается использовать `static_cast`, если не получается, использует `reinterpret_cast`. Далее, если нужно, использует `const_cast`.

Ещё один аргумент - всякие `static_cast` легче искать поиском.

Ещё две ссылки на треды, где это активно обсуждается - [хабр](http://habrahabr.ru/post/106294/) и [rsdn.org](http://www.rsdn.org/forum/cpp/3812985).

Comment: Вот между static_cast и (int) явно **больше минусов у static_cast**, т.к. контекст самой арифметической операции теряется, если в них участвуют такие длинные сущности. Не поддерживаю больной энтузиазм в использовании таких явных кастов направо и налево. Начинающих можно понять - интерес, но злоупотребление топеров такой практикой говорит только о их незрелости.

Answer (score 16):

Проблема в том, что `()`-приведение типов может означать миллион разных вещей, о которых вы даже не догадываетесь, в зависимости от контекста.

Во-первых, оно выполняет преобразование арифметических типов. Если вам нужен `int` из `double`, оно вычисляет целую часть. Если вам нужен `char` из `long`, оно отбрасывает значащие разряды.

Во-вторых, оно отбрасывает спецификаторы `const` и `volatile`. Незаметно для вас.

В-третьих, оно преобразовывает `int` в указатель и обратно.

В-четвёртых, оно преобразовывает указатели вверх и вниз по иерархии наследования.

В-пятых, оно преобразовывает указатели как `reinterpret_cast`, ориентируясь на битовое представление.

В отличие от этого, `static_cast` делает только преобразование арифметических типов (для арифметических типов) и преобразование указателей вверх-вниз по иерархии наследования (для указателей). [Вы всё ещё можете привести друг к другу совсем «незнакомые» типы в два шага, через `void*`, но это уже нужно сделать явно и невозможно сделать по ошибке. Вот [полный список правил](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast).]

Во многих случаях вам не нужна безумная мощь `()`-приведения, потому что она может скрыть ошибки. Примеры:

```
void f(char *str);

void g(const _TCHAR *txt)
{
    f((char*)txt);               // компилируется
    f(static_cast<char*>(txt));  // не компилируется
}
```

Здесь вызов, скорее всего, не должен скомпилироваться, потому что функция `f` ожидает однобайтную строку, и наверняка не готова работать с `wchar_t*`. Если же функция `f` может работать с такими строками, можно использовать `reinterpret_cast`. Для случая `()`-приведения у вас нету возможности различить эти случаи.

```
void f(char *str);

void g(const char *txt)
{
    f((char*)txt);               // компилируется
    f(static_cast<char*>(txt));  // не компилируется
}
```

Здесь вызов опять-таки не должен скомпилироваться, потому что функция `f` имеет право модифицировать строку, а символы в `txt` модифицировать нельзя.

Конечно, в таких простых примерах проблема видна "невооружённым глазом". Но если функция `g` — шаблон, и точный тип `txt` неизвестен в точке определения функции, вам намного сложнее отловить подобные ошибки. В этом случае `static_cast` позволит поймать их ещё на этапе компиляции, не приводя к аварийному завершению программы.

Comment: Хороший ответ.

--

А ведь можно сказать и так:

все приведения типов С++ - это страховка для тех, кто пишет по принципу - "напишу-ка я вот такие буквы - вдруг заработает?".

А правильный подход - "не знаешь - не трогай".

Comment: static_cast делает только преобразование арифметических типов (для арифметических типов) и преобразование указателей по иерархии наследования (для указателей)

Comment: @IAZ: частично: http://ideone.com/wkpEhT
Спасибо, поправил.

Comment: @VladD: static_cast для указателей работает "по доверию" и не делает никаких проверок, т.е. можно приводить любые указатели друг к другу. Только проверяет на факт наследования одного класса от другого, но не сам объект!

Comment: @avp: "не знаешь - не трогай" -- очень правильно, иначе undefined behaviour практически неизбежно.

Comment: @VladD в обратном направлении static_cast указатели тоже прекрасно преобразует: http://ideone.com/8ON4Dr

Comment: Более того, именно этот случай - основной, потому что к корню указатели без проблем преобразуются неявно.

Comment: @PavelMayorov: И правда. Старый ответ, 13-го года ещё :-D Исправил, спасибо!

Answer (score 7):

Выражение вида `(T)` описано в главе *5.4 Explicit type conversion (cast notation) [expr.cast]*.

Оно по очереди пробует следующие преобразования

- `const_cast`
- `static_cast`
- `static_cast` и затем `const_cast`
- `reinterpret_cast`
- `reinterpret_cast` и затем `const_cast`

При этом для `static_cast` снимается ограничение на видимость базового класса при преобразованиях между указателями/ссылками на классы потомки и базовые классы. (А так же при преобразованиях между указателями на члены классов).

```
class Base {};
class Derived : private Base {};
Derived* d = new Derived();

//static_cast<Base*>(d); // не скомпилируется: Base недоступна (private)
Base* b = (Base*)d; // OK

//static_cast<Derived*>(b); // не скомпилируется: Base недоступна (private)
Derived* d2 = (Derived*)b; // OK
```

Если одновременно возможны несколько вариантов преобразований, то код не скомпилируется. (Например в случае множественного наследования могут быть два базовых класса с одним типом)

Можно преобразовать неполные типы классов. При этом стандарт не указывает какой именно каст будет сделан, `static_cast` или `reinterpret_cast`.

```
struct X;
struct Y;
X* blind_cast(Y* y) {
    //return static_cast<X*>(y); // не скомпилируется: неполные типы
    return (X*)y; // OK
}
```

Если мы определим эти типы

```
struct Base1 { int some; };
struct X {};
struct Y : Base1, X {};
```

То выражение `static_cast<X*>(y) == blind_cast(y)` может быть как `true`, так и `false`:

- если в момент генерации кода компилятор увидит полные определения типа, то он сделает `static_cast`,
- если `blind_cast` компилируется отдельно, то компилятор не увидит полные определения типа и сделает `reinterpret_cast`, тогда результат `blind_cast` будет на самом деле указывать на `Base1`, и сравнение выдаст `false`.

Comment: Что-то я подозреваю, что пустая структура при наследовании ничего не подвинет. Кинь что ли в неё какой-нибудь int...