# Приведение числовых типов через reinterpret_cast

Tags: c++

Если мы используем `reinterpret_cast` для приведения указателя к указателю, объекта к указателю или указателя к объекту, то приведение осуществляется корректно.

```
int n = 0;
char* c = reinterpret_cast<char*>(n);
int another_value = reinterpret_cast<int>(c);
```

Почему `reinterpret_cast` не позволяет осуществлять приведение на простых форматах?
Такой код не собирается:

```
int a = 0;
char b = reinterpret_cast<char>(a);
```

по Страуструпу:

> `reinterpret_cast` управляет преобразованиями между несвязанными типами, например целых в указатели или указателей в другие(несвязанные) указатели.

по Майерсу:

> `reinterpret_cast` предназначен для низкоуровневых приведений, которые порождают зависимые от реализации (то есть непереносимые) результаты, например приведение указателя к `int`.

Итак, и указатель к указателю, и указатель к `int`, и `int` к указателю посредством `reinterpret_cast` приводятся.

Алена Л. в [блоге](http://alenacpp.blogspot.ru/2005/08/c.html) пишет:

> `reinterpret_cast` - самое нахальное приведение типов. Не портируемо, результат может быть некорректным, никаких проверок не делается. Считается, что вы лучше компилятора знаете как на самом деле обстоят дела, а он тихо подчиняется. Не может быть приведено одно значение к другому значению. Обычно используется, чтобы привести указатель к указателю, указатель к целому, целое к указателю. Умеет также работать со ссылками.

Хорошо, одно значение к другому не может быть приведено. Почему эту возможность не запилили?

Comment: Так а что эта "возможность" должна была бы делать, если бы ее "запилили"??? Какой результат вы ожидаете получить от такого `reinterpret_cast`?

Comment: Интересный вопрос. Вот примерные ожидания от этой "возможности": создавать новый объект - клон того, к которому обращаюсь, и остальное аналогично приведению к ссылке. Почему клон - потому что если не создавать новый объект, то функционал был бы идентичен приведению по ссылке.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`reinterpret_cast`, как видно из названия, предназначен в первую очередь для выполнения *переинтерпретации памяти*. То есть когда вы приводите указатель типа `T *` к указателю типа `U *`, то предполагается, что вы это делаете для того, чтобы обратиться к памяти исходного объекта типа `T`, как к памяти объекта типа `U`. В этом и заключается *переинтерпретации памяти*. (Разумеется, легальность такого доступа зависит еще от массы посторонних факторов.)

`reinterpret_cast` также поддерживает аналог такого указательного преобразования, но в варианте со ссылками вместо указателей, т.е. вы можете сделать

```
T t;
U &u = reinterpret_cast<U &>(t);
```

и далее получать доступ к памяти объекта `t` как объекта типа `U`.

Также на `reinterpret_cast` дополнительно "повесили" побочную функциональность - приведение между указательными и целыми типами. Все.

А вот чего вы хотели добиться, выполняя `reinterpret_cast` типа `int` к типу `char` - не ясно. Если вам нужна именно переинтерпретация памяти, то это делается так

```
int a = 0;
char b = reinterpret_cast<char &>(a);
```

то есть целевой тип должен быть ссылкой.

Ваш же вариант выглядит как обычное преобразование типов, выполняемое `static_cast`, а не `reinterpret_cast`. Вся идея разнообразия типов кастов в С++ как раз и сводится к разделению обязанностей между ними с минимальными пересечениями.

Comment: +1 за `reinterpret_cast` на ссылках. Даже не думал о таком.

Answer (score 5):

Смотрите.

Преобразования бывают двух типов: меняющие внутреннее представление, и не меняющие его.

Преобразование `int` в `double` меняет внутреннее представление, `double` имеет хитрый бинарный layout с мантиссой и порядком. Преобразование целочисленных типов тоже меняет внутреннее представление, если у них разные длины.

А вот смысл `reinterpret_cast`, наоборот, в том, что он меняет тип объекта с *точки зрения компилятора*, и (кроме возможных патологических компиляторов) никак не отображается в объектном коде. Вы ж помните, что объект — это просто набор бит в памяти и его тип, позволяющий интерпретировать его? `reinterpret_cast` просто просит компилятор интерпретировать его по-другому, не меняя сами биты в памяти.

---

А преобразование, которое умеет делать всё, преобразовывать и числовые типы, и указатели, уже запилили. Это [C-style cast](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/199630/10105). Правда, из-за избыточной мощи его использование не рекомендуется — именно потому, что он может и числа преобразовать, и указатели, и вашего кота, даже если вы этого и не хотели.

Comment: _"не меняя сами биты в памяти"_ - интересный момент - каст указателя в число. Что если битность числа не совпадёт с битностью указателя?

Comment: @Qwertiy: Не компилируется: http://ideone.com/GkL1XS

Comment: Да, с int'ом - [тоже](http://ideone.com/XPacfk). Неожиданно. А как же тогда кастить - всегда в long? Ведь всякие if sizeof не прокатывают?

Comment: @Qwertiy: В `size_t`? Он вроде нужного размера. Проблема осложняется ещё тем, что разные указатели могут быть разного размера.

Comment: А такое где-нибудь реально встречается, ну кроме старых компиляторов, где были near и far?

Comment: @Qwertiy для указателей есть `intptr_t` и `uintptr_t`.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Например, для виртуального наследования. [Вот тут](http://www.phpcompiler.org/articles/virtualinheritance.html) когда-то была отличная статья, осталось только [тут](https://github.com/pbiggar/phpcompiler.org/blob/master/public_html/articles/virtualinheritance.html).